# I used pyinstaller to turn my .py file to a executable file, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, file, pyinstaller, exe, executable

EDIT: I'm using the "random" library and the "os" library, could they be interfering with the file's execution?

Good morning, I'm creating a hangman game that runs all in the terminal, doesn't open any graphical window, I used pyinstaller to turn my .py file into an executable. When I run it through the command ./My_file it works normally, but if I try to run it by double clicking it doesn't open anything! Does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Which operating system?  I'm guessing Linux.  Double-clicking in what?  If you have created a desktop icon, check the properties to make sure it creates a console.  You'll need to create an `xterm` to host your console.

Comment: Start by opening a console window and running your program. That way you have some hope of seeing the error message before the window closes. After that: the `pyinstaller` documentation has a very helpful section called *When things go wrong.* I suggest you work through it.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes i use Linux, i double-click in the executable file, but it doesn't run

Comment: TimRoberts and how can i create an xterm?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/182700/desktop-shortcut-for-terminal-command